# Is there a way to write a multiline equation using the LateXiT software?

Tags: equations, mac, latexit

Sometimes for something simple I write in Microsoft Word, but since I still want to insert equations fast, I use the free LateXiT software on my mac. This allows me to write the equation in a latex format and produces an png image which I drag and drop into my word document. Problem is that I did not find a way to write multiline equations with it yet, its there a way? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to import the split package, while the solution was much simpler than that. To write multiline equations in LateXiT just use \\ at the points where you want to change line for a new equation

Answer (score 1):

Ending a line with \\ does not seem to work in the

```
$$....math stuff....more stuff....$$
```

context. But what does work in that context is to just end with $$ and start again on the next line with a new $$ like so

```
$$....math stuff..$$
$$..more stuff....$$
```

For example,

```
$$\Re\Bigg\{\frac{4\alpha  e^{-\beta  x}}{\pi ^2}\bigg[- H_{\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{\beta }{\alpha }-2\right)}+2 i^{-\frac{\beta }{\alpha }} B_{-e^{2 \alpha  x}}\left(\frac{\beta }{2 \alpha },0\right)+\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{\beta }{4 \alpha }\right)-2 \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{\beta }{2 \alpha }\right)$$
$$-2 B_{e^{2 \alpha  x}}\left(\frac{\beta }{2 \alpha },0\right)+2 e^{\beta  x} \ln (\coth (\alpha  x))-\gamma -2 i \pi -\ln (4)\bigg]\Bigg\}$$
```

[image]

The context here is LaTeXiT for Mac. For those who are unfamiliar with that, I add that LaTeXiT for Mac is a "scratch pad" that comes preloaded with default hidden but editable LaTeX commands allowing one to debug LaTeX code for equations. A screen shot follows:

[image]

Note that LaTeXiT requires a MacTeX (TeX Live) installation to work.

Comment: Are you using PlainTeX or LaTeX to compile this code snippet? Please clarify.

Comment: @Miro The question and answer refer to the program LaTeXiT for Mac, and only to LaTeXiT for Mac. One can download that program here https://download.cnet.com/LaTeXiT/3000-2053_4-66890.html

Comment: @Mico Full disclosure, I am using Version 2.16.1

Comment: Thanks for providing this clarification.

Comment: @Mico That you asked suggests a need to explain LaTeXiT for Mac, see edit.

Comment: It might be worth noting that LaTeXiT requires a MacTeX (TeX Live) installation to work.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL So noted, thanks.